# How to shorten this VBA Code (preferably with loop)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I shorten this sample code (preferably with a loop)?

```
    NPCodes_Doc1.Close False    
    NPCodes_Doc2.Close False        
    NPCodes_Doc3.Close False        
    NPCodes_Doc4.Close False        
    NPCodes_Doc5.Close False
```

The VBA for MS Word that I created is getting the "Procedure too large" error and hence, I want to shorten my code.

The `NPCodes_Doc` variables are .docx files that are being opened and contents pasted into the main doc.

There are 118 .docx files related to this... Here's one of the 118 blocks of If statements to give you the idea:

```
If NPCodes Like "*Document1*" Then
Set NPCodes_Doc117 = Documents.Open(NPCodes_Path & "\" & "Document1.docx")
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 12
    Selection.Copy
    Documents("Code Template.docm").Activate
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.Paste
End If
```

So there are 118 documents for the code to choose from and  with every match, that doc is opened and copied into the main one. After all of the 118 docs have been searched, the matched (opened and copied) docs are then closed with:

```
On Error Resume Next
        NPCodes_Doc1.Close False    
        NPCodes_Doc2.Close False        
        NPCodes_Doc3.Close False        
        NPCodes_Doc4.Close False        
        NPCodes_Doc5.Close False 
        ....   _Doc118.Close False
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: You have created **118** copies of your code, painstakingly changing a few digits in each copy, before asking yourself if a loop maybe might be a better idea? Next time, please think about using a loop before you even create **one** copy of your code. Avoiding *"procedure too large"* errors is not even the main goal here.

Comment: Also, think about using Word styles instead of applying individual format settings to the entire text of a document.

Comment: Haha! That  is awfully correct. I just did it coz it worked and never thought of something like a 'Procedure too large" error to occur. I'm just a VA who got into coding and loved it. I never had the educational background but am super excited to learn! :D

Comment: Well then this is your opportunity to learn something very fundamental. **A**) Don't copy and paste code. Ever. If you need to do a thing more than once, write a loop. Even if you need to do it only twice, write a loop. **B**) Don't use variable names that end with a number (like `thing1`, `thing2`, ..., `thing118`). This is almost always an indication that you are doing something wrong. Stop at the very moment when you feel you could use a `thing2` variable and think about how to modularize your code so that you don't need to do that.

Comment: Rewriting code so that it does the same thing but sucks less is called "refactoring". One technique of refactoring is called "extract method". I want you to make a new `Sub` that contains *one* copy of your code block. Identify all the variable bits in this block and turn them into parameters for the `Sub`. Then replace each of your 118 code blocks with calls to that `Sub`, with different parameters. *Then* identify how parameters change in these 118 `Sub` calls you have now. And *that* will be the basis of how to turn them into a single-line loop that runs 118 times.

Comment: @Tomalak: Thank you! Point B is quite common sense but I'm surprised I have not thought of it that way :) I think I'll stick with copy pasting codes for now though, but I really am liking the fact that I can now somehow code  simple  ones from scratch. And yes, I've been fascinated by looping since I've 'learned' (heard) about it. I just don't have the skills and experience to use it as much as i'd love to.

Comment: @JohnnyDerpp I edited your question to remove a large amount of clutter and idle chatter. When writing questions on StackOverflow, please be concise and stick to the point.

Comment: Oooh,  doing that refactoring stuff will fall according to plan. How do I do the loop for the closing of the docs, though? I'm quite stumped coz really, I think that's one easy task, even for a newb like me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Thank you! Really needed it since being concise is not one of my strengths. My question makes so much sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken on its own, this code

```
NPCodes_Doc1.Close False    
NPCodes_Doc2.Close False        
NPCodes_Doc3.Close False        
NPCodes_Doc4.Close False        
NPCodes_Doc5.Close False
```

cannot be shortened. `NPCodes_Doc1`, `NPCodes_Doc2` etc. are completely separate variables, and there's no way to refer to them collectively.

Is there any reason you would want to open all of your 118 document at once? I'm guessing not. You should probably restructure your code to open only one document at a time, copy-paste from it, then close it, and move on to the next document. Repeat. <-- That's a loop right there.

I can't see your specifics, so I can't write working code for you, but it would look something like this:

```
Dim doc As Document
For i = 1 To 118
    Set doc = Documents.Open(NPCodes_Path & "\" & "Document" & i & ".docx")
    '
    ' put code to copy and paste here
    '
    doc.Close False
Next i
```

Comment: I've been thinking of something similar but can't put my finger on it,..Your code makes so much sense. The problem is that the docs don't have numbers in them so the 'i' cannot be used inside the documents.open 'parameter'( is that the term)?  But hey! I can just add numbers into the filenames, yeah? Let me know if you have any idea. For now, I'll see what I can come up with using this code. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like we overlooked the IF part, the "If NPCodes Like "*Document1*" Then". 

How do we fit that in this code? The 'NPCodes' are actually data from an Excel file that was scraped off the internet beforehand. No numbers in it, just contains name of places and goes something like: "Los Angeles Park". I would then need to match that with the current 118 documents we have. So not all 118 gets opened, just the ones that matched. Unfortunately for the "NPCodes", unlike the documents, they cannot be edited (easily, i guess)  to contain numbers for the loop to seamlessly work. Any ideas?

Comment: Continuation:
To make matters worse, some documents refer to one and the same place, with suffixes in the filenames like: "Los Angeles Park - Upper" and "Los Angeles Park - Lower", requiring me to reference other cells in the Excel file other than the NPCodes to get the exact match.I may have gone off topic now,. feel free to tell me what to do :)

Comment: I'm finding it difficult and time-consuming to parse your narrative into a task description. You should probably focus on producing a clear and concise description of what you're trying to achieve -- what are the inputs, what are the desired outputs. Only then does it make sense to ask for help.

Comment: I just realised i got the answer to my question: Separate variables cannot be referred to collectively / cannot be shortened. Your code has been most helpful. Thank you! I'll have a play around with it and just post a separate question if i still get stuck :)